# Добавить поддомен через js

Tags: javascript

Я делаю переадресацию на поддомен в зависимости от выбранного города. У меня получается сделать редирект только на конкретный URL, а нужно чтобы поддомен подставлялся к любой ссылке.

Вот как делаю я:

```js
 window.location.href = "http://msk.mysite.com/";
```

Если человек находится на странице http://mysite.com/catalog/item-1/, мне нужно чтобы вся ссылка забиралась и перед моим доменом mysite.com подставлялся субдомен msk.

Очень надеюсь на вашу помощь.

Answer (score 1):

```
location.href = location.href.replace(/^https?:\/\//, "$&msk.")
```

Answer (score 1):

Просто и эффективно:

```
if (window.location.hostname.indexOf('msk.')) 
  window.location.hostname = 'msk.' + window.location.hostname;
```

Метод `indexOf` в данном случае очень удобен: вернет `0` если поддомен уже добавлен куда нужно (в начало имени хоста), `-1` если его подстрока не найдена, и положительное значение если его подстрока найдена не там где нужно.
Любые значения отличные от нуля будут преобразованы в `true`, и условие выполнится.
Таким образом, редирект будет происходить во всех случаях, когда это необходимо.